# TypeError: cannot pickle '_asyncio.Future' object

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am making face recognition attendance system using python, whenever a request comes to WebSocket it opens a new camera in a new process using multiprocessing. Every thing works fine but when it comes to send message from process created with multiprocessing, I get an error (TypeError: cannot pickle '_asyncio.Future' object) (COMPLETE ERROR IS GIVEN BELOW), The error "Can't pickle local object" occurs because the Process class from the multiprocessing module requires the arguments passed to its target function to be picklable. Pickling is the process of converting a Python object into a byte stream so that it can be stored on disk or transmitted over a network. In my code, I'm passing the websocket object as an argument to the process_camera function, which is intended to be executed in a separate process. However, the websocket object is an instance of a class that is not picklable, meaning it cannot be serialized into a byte stream. This is because the websocket object contains references to underlying socket connections and other resources that cannot be serialized.

*Any idea how I can send messages from multiple process to other side.*

**Extra Information:**
I'm using [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) (a framework which is used to make cross-platform desktop applications with only HTML, CSS and JS.) with python and I am using websockets as a meduim of communication between them. Each time user want to open camera from front-end, a request using websockets goes to python to open camera in a separate process and start face recognition, I want to get responses from those camera process but getting errors.

My minimal code with all libraries I used:

```
import asyncio
import sqlite3
import pickle
import face_recognition
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np
import websockets
import json
from multiprocessing import Process


def process_camera(id, camera_port, websocket):
    websocket.send({"id": id, "camera": camera_port})
   
async def start_server(websocket, path):
    try:
        # Get the JSON data from the WebSocket connection
        async for message in websocket:
            data = json.loads(message)
            if data:
                # Extract the subject ID from the JSON data
                subject_id = data.get('subject_id')
                if subject_id == 1:
                    camera_port = 0
                else:
                    camera_port = 1

                # Start camera capture in a separate process
                p = Process(target=process_camera, args=(subject_id, camera_port, websocket))
                p.start()

    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK:
        print("Client connection closed")


async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(start_server, "localhost", 8765):
        await asyncio.Future()  # Keep the server running indefinitely


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

ERROR:

```
connection handler failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abdul Rafey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\server.py", line 236, in handler     
    await self.ws_handler(self)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul Rafey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\server.py", line 1175, in _ws_handler
    return await cast(
  File "c:/Users/Abdul Rafey/OneDrive/Desktop/electron app/electron-quick-start/python/camera.py", line 31, in start_server
    p.start()
  File "C:\Users\Abdul Rafey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul Rafey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul Rafey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul Rafey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul Rafey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_asyncio.Future' object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Abdul Rafey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 107, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.duplicate(pipe_handle,
  File "C:\Users\Abdul Rafey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 79, in duplicate
    return _winapi.DuplicateHandle(
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```