# How to communicate between Electron Framework and python

Tags: python, electron, communication

I am trying to make a face recognition attendance system for schools using Python and Electron. I am using multiprocessing in Python which will create a new process for each camera which will open parallelly to record attendance for students. I achieved success in setting a communication medium between Electron and Python but when it comes to multiprocessing in Python, I got errors. I tried to set communication medium using ZMQ, Flask and WebSocket but I failed each time when using multiprocessing.

is there any way of communication which allow

- bi-directional communication between electron and each process       created with multiprocessing library in python for opening camera and perform face recognition.
- less over heads
- fast and efficient
- cross-platform
- work offline
- work well with multiprocessing

Comment: You some seem to have a specific problem but made a question out of it that it too broad for Stack Overflow. Focus on the problem and present it in details with the relevant code.

Comment: Yes! For example ZMQ.

Comment: I posted my problem earlier on many platforms including stack overflow but haven't got any solution. Heres the link when I was working with websockets for communication and got errors.            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78109856/typeerror-cannot-pickle-asyncio-future-object

Comment: Now I'm just asking for library which can be used for communication. Library can be like a messaging library like zmq or anything,but that should work with multiprocessing